# UX Task Success and Page views

Tags: task-completion

I have a funnel setup for a page which tracks A,B,C button click to complete the task. You can only do this if there is an item on this page.

My question is should I track the page views at the start of this funnel? I worry about correlating it to success metrics because there could be times when the user is just looking at the items on a page or lands on the page without the intention of completing the task (ie; notification feed).
However I also want to track to see if any users want to action but are getting stuck using the first A button.

How do other UX'ers track task success and how many times a user landed on that page without knowing the users intention?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**No extra track is bad. With more data, more accurate you can be. I just suggest you find a way to identify the user behaviour at the first step to not affect the analyses.**

About CTA's track, I like to create a funnel with the user decision process and for it, I normally create triggers to answer these questions:

- How many steps do I have on this funnel?
- What does the user looking for in each step?
- From where the user comes to each step and why?
- What's the conversion point in each step?
- What is disturbing the user attention?
- Why they are doing this?
- How can I simplify this step?
- What the expected conversion rate?

And then I create a lot of "What if..." and make A/B tests or MVT tests.

*P.S.: A step does not require to be a page, could be a question like "This website offer what I'm looking for?", "This company is reliable?" or "Does they have this product in red?".*